# Add a specific tag to default tag list

Tags: tags

Is there a way to add a specific tag to default list? I mean, I want 45 default tag and one specific (chose by me) among them.

I tried with `include` parameter of `wp_tag_cloud()` but as a result I received only this one tag from `include` on list.

EDIT:

To be more clear: `wp_tag_cloud()` by default outputs list of 45 most used tags. I'd like to set up these 45 tags + one, chose by me tag among them. E.g: when WP displays by default list of tags: Tag A, Tag B, Tag C, I'd like to have: Tag A, Tag B, Tag C, Other Tag. It might be 46 tags as a result or this chosen tag might replace some from default list - this is less important. The most important is to have this specific tag in this default list. I could do this by add all these default tags IDs + ID of this specific one in `include` parameter, but it's a lot to do. I'm wondering if there is a faster solution?

Comment: Where do you want to add tags?

Comment: I have wp_tag_cloud() function on page. I tried to edit its parameters using include but without success.

Comment: Can you paste code you used?

Comment: `<?php wp_tag_cloud('include=5056'); ?>` and I see as a result only tag with ID put in include.

Comment: This is normal. As you set one id tag, it will show one tag, normal behaviour. If you leave it empty, it should show all tags. So, how much tags do you have at all and what do you mean by 45 default tags and one specific tag? This is not clear for me.

Comment: `wp_tag_cloud()` by default outputs list of 45 most used tags. I'd like to set up these 45 tags + one, chose by me tag among them. E.g: when WP displays by default list of tags: Tag A, Tag B, Tag C, I'd like to have: Tag A, Tag B, Tag C, Other Tag. It might be 46 tags as a result or this chosen tag might replace some from default list - this is less important. The most important is to have this specific tag in this default list. I could do this by add all these default tags IDs + ID of this specific one in `include` parameter, but it's a lot to do. I'm wondering if there is a faster solution.

Comment: Now I've got it. Just checked a source code of wp_tag_cloud function and there is no right hook to add one extra term. wp_tag_cloud calls wp_generate_tag_cloud which has few filters you can try. Maybe `tag_cloud_sort` filter is suitable for your purpose. It receives and returns array of terms, so you can call get_term there to get your specific term, merge it with default terms array and return it. Unfortunatelly, I can't test this filter right now. Can you handle it by yourself or you need help?

Comment: I think the best solution is to simply output the term yourself as HTML and append it to the results. You could filter on [`get_terms_args`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/get_terms_args/) but include is full inclusive, meaning it will only return the single included term. Might be better off copying the whole `wp_tag_cloud()` method and duplicating it to suit your needs.